# Why is hadoop mapReduce with python failing but the scripts are working on command line?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm trying to implement a simple Hadoop map reduce example using Cloudera 5.5.0
The map & reduce steps should be implemented using Python 2.6.6

Problem:

- If the scripts are being executed on the unix command line they're working perfectly fine and producing the expected output.

cat join2*.txt | ./join3_mapper.py | sort | ./join3_reducer.py

- **But** executing the scripts as a hadoop task **terribly fails**:

hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -input /user/cloudera/inputTV/join2_gen*.txt -output /user/cloudera/output_tv -mapper /home/cloudera/join3_mapper.py -reducer /home/cloudera/join3_reducer.py -numReduceTasks 1

`16/01/06 12:32:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452069211060_0026_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)`

- The mapper works, if the hadoop command is executed with -numReduceTasks 0,
  the hadoop job is executing only map step, ends successfully and the output directory contains the result files from map step.
- I guess there must be something wrong with the reduce step then ?
- The stderr logs in Hue shows nothing relevant:

Log Upload Time: Wed Jan 06 12:33:10 -0800 2016
Log Length: 222
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Code of the scripts:
1st file: join3_mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   line       = line.strip()   #strip out carriage return
   tuple2  = line.split(",")   #split line, into key and value, returns a list

   if len(tuple2) == 2:
      key = tuple2[0]
      value = tuple2[1]
      if value == 'ABC':
         print('%s\t%s' % (key, value) )
      elif value.isdigit():
         print('%s\t%s' % (key, value) )
```

The 2nd file: join3_reducer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

last_key      = None              #initialize these variables
running_total = 0
abcFound =False;
this_key      = None

# -----------------------------------
# Loop the file
#  --------------------------------
for input_line in sys.stdin:
    input_line = input_line.strip()

    # --------------------------------
    # Get Next Key value pair, splitting at tab
    # --------------------------------
    tuple2 = input_line.split("\t") 

    this_key = tuple2[0]    
    value = tuple2[1]
    if value.isdigit():
        value = int(value) 

    # ---------------------------------
    # Key Check part
    #    if this current key is same 
    #          as the last one Consolidate
    #    otherwise  Emit
    # ---------------------------------
    if last_key == this_key:     
        if value == 'ABC':  # filter for only ABC in TV shows
            abcFound=True;
        else:
            if isinstance(value, (int,long) ): 
                running_total += value   

    else:
        if last_key:         #if this key is different from last key, and the previous 
                             #   (ie last) key is not empy,
                             #   then output 
                             #   the previous <key running-count>
           if abcFound:
              print('%s\t%s' % (last_key, running_total) )
              abcFound=False;

        running_total = value    #reset values
        last_key = this_key

if last_key == this_key:
    print('%s\t%s' % (last_key, running_total) )
```

I have tried various different ways of declaring the input file to the hadoop command, no difference, no success.

What am I doing wrong ?  Hints, ideas are very appreciated thank you

Comment: Don't you need toolrunner to be able to run a jar file from the command line?

Comment: Also, aren't jar files for Java programs?

Comment: I'm not executing a jar file myself, I'm executing hadoop command and tell hadoop to execute the declared jar file. The rest following the library path are parameters related to the hadoop-streaming.jar and are related to the MapReduce action which is executed. yes, jar files are java programs

Answer (score 1):

What a lucky punch, fighting with that one for days and know I got it working:

Since the local (unix) execution of

```
cat join2_gen*.txt | ./join2_mapper.py | sort | ./join2_reducer.py
```

worked fine I had the idea to use 1 merged input file, instead of the provided 6 input files, so:

```
cat join2_gen*.txt >> mergedinputFile.txt

hdfs dfs -put mergedInputFile.txt /user/cloudera/input
```

then executing the very same hadoop command again, directing the input to the mergedInputFile in the input folder --> **perfect result**, no problem, no exception job done.

For me it raises the question:

- Why is it working with one merged input file but now with providing the smaller 6 files ?? No idea (yet)

Comment: I'm having the same problem! It's working perfect in serial mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all the input text files in one directory and then passing the directory as the input. This way you won't have to merge all your input files